# how to detect keyevent in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've write a web shell with javascript, but it doesn't work in firefox. But in IE and Chrome, it's fine. I've found that in firefox my script can't get the keyevent. So how can I fix this bug? Thanks a lot :)

Shell: http://cdqzoi.com

Script Address: http://cdqzoi.com/console.js
The following code is part of the script above, which handles keyevent.

```
this.keydown=function(){
    key=event;
    keyN=event.keyCode?event.keyCode:event.which?event.which:event.charCode;
    if(keyN==0)return;
    if((keyN==8)||(keyN==116)||(key.ctrlKey && keyN==82)){
        if(keyN==8 & !lock){
            this.command = this.command.substr(0,this.command.length-1);
            document.getElementById("console").innerHTML=getPrefix(this.transmit)+this.command;
        }
        try{
            event.returnValue=false;
            event.keyCode=0;
        }catch(e){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    keyN=0;
}
this.keypress=function(){
    key=event;
    keyN=event.keyCode?event.keyCode:event.which?event.which:event.charCode;
    if(keyN==0)return;
    if(!lock){
        if(keyN==13){
            if(this.transmit==0){
                user=this.command;
                document.getElementById("_console").innerHTML+=document.getElementById("console").innerHTML+"<br />";
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML='';
                this.transmit=1;
                this.st=1;
            }else
            if(this.transmit==1){
                this.st=0;
                pass=this.command;
                document.getElementById("_console").innerHTML+=document.getElementById("console").innerHTML+"<br />";
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML="";
                con.login(user,pass);
                try{
                    event.returnValue=false;
                    event.keyCode=0;
                }catch(e){
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                keyN=0;
                return;
            }else
            if(this.transmit==2){con.execute(this.command);}
            this.command='';
        }else if(keyN==8){
        }else{
            this.command=this.command+String.fromCharCode(keyN);
        }
        if(this.st==0)document.getElementById("console").innerHTML=getPrefix(this.transmit)+this.command;
        else document.getElementById("console").innerHTML=getPrefix(1);
    }
    try{
        event.returnValue=false;
        event.keyCode=0;
    }catch(e){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    keyN=0;
}
```

Comment: You're relying on global `event` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your handlers like this:

```
this.keypress = function(e) {
  var ev = window.event || e;
  // use ev from here onwards
```

Reason is that IE (and apparently, Chrome too, chooses to pass event data via a global variable rather than a function argument).

Comment: It works, thanks. But we should use "var event;" before you use this.